# Subscribe simulated data using OPC Publisher from OPC UA server

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, opc-ua, azure-iot-edge

I'm able to connect the OPC UA simulation Server and OPC Publisher and could see the messages on the Azure portal.

Is it mandatory to mention the node details to get data or Is there any possibility to subscribe all the data from the OPC UA server

i.e. need to provide the node details to subscribe

```
      {
        "Id": "ns=3;i=1001",
        "OpcSamplingInterval": 2000,
        "OpcPublishingInterval": 5000,
        "DisplayName": "Counter"
      },
      {
        "Id": "ns=6;s=MyLevel",
        "OpcSamplingInterval": 2000,
        "OpcPublishingInterval": 5000,
        "DisplayName": "MyLevel"
      }
    ]
```

Also, OPC UA server if the subscriber joined in between. Is there any options to read a message from the beginning
or
if the subscriber is not available in between due to some issue for 2-3 sec, does the server captures the missed messages and send them when the subscriber is available again?

Comment: You are not very clear about what you are doing. Assuming you are talking about Prosys OPC UA Simulation Server, it doesn't publish anything yet on it's own. So where is your Publisher? And yes, you will need to prepare a dataset with specific variables.

Comment: Prosys OPC UA Simulation Server and Publisher are running on my local server. Also, I can pass the parameter about the Azure IoT Hub and device URLs to Publisher when starting the docker container. I could see the messages/count in the Azure portal as well. 

My question is, for example, I've more than 100 nodes/variables. Do I need to mention all the node details in the Publisher config files to push the messages to Azure IoT Hub? 

Is it possible to push the messages from a single Publisher to different Azure IoT devices?

Comment: Yes, you need to add them all in Dataset(s) and map them to the Publisher Connection(s) accordingly.
The SamplePublisher defines the ClientId per connection. To provide different DeviceIds, I guess you will need to use different connections. But, I don't know if that works in practice, if they are having the same address.

Comment: See also documentation here: [Microsoft OPC Publisher - Standalone Mode](https://github.com/Azure/Industrial-IoT/blob/main/docs/modules/publisher.md)